# Rails 2.3: how to get ActiveRecord errors types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm on Rails 2.3.8; I have this model:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :foo

  def foo
    errors.add_to_base :foo_error
  end
end
```

My purpose is to retrieve the types of the errors, for example something like this:

```
c = Coupon.new
c.valid?
c.errors.types #=> [[:base, :foo_error]]
```

I managed to retrieve the error types, but with a really weird monkeypatch:

```
# in config/initializers/active_record_errors_types.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Errors
    def types
      instance_variable_get(:@errors).map do |k,v| 
        [ k.to_sym, v[0].instance_variable_get(:@type) ]
      end
    end
  end
end

c = Coupon.new
c.valid?
c.errors.types #=> [[:base, :foo_error]]
```

Do you know a better way to retrieve error types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In rails 6, no monkeypatching needed:

```
c.errors.details.values.flatten.map{|h| h[:error] }
```

Comment: I forgot I asked this question! The answer is correct, gonna accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Errors
    def types
      @errors.values.flatten.map(&:type).uniq
    end
  end
end
```

If you  want to avoid the monkey patching you can directly make the call on the AR object.

```
user.errors.instance_variable_get(:@errors).values.flatten.map(&:type).uniq
```

Alternatively you can do the following:

```
[].tap {|types| user.errors.each_error{|a,e| types << e.type}}.uniq
```

Comment: it monkeypatches `ActiveRecord::Errors`, I would avoid... can be possible that there are no clean ways to retrieve the error types?

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: it doesn't work: `undefined method 'values' for #<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x7f2960cc0228>`... it works using `instance_variable_get`: `user.errors.instance_variable_get(:@errors).values.flatten.map(&:type).uniq`, but it is as weird as my try (but refactorized :) )

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look.